# Scroll in 100% steps inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div that contains several children with 100% height. On scrolling I always want to go down or up exactly the height of one child, so 100%. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to prevent scrolling multiple steps at a time. I tried `event.preventDefault()` and also using timeouts, but none worked yet.

[Check out the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RancoR/2sap5m6w/21/) to see what I've got so far - and what the issue look like exactly.

```js
$container = $('#container');
var doScroll = true;
var top = 0;

$container.on("scroll", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if (doScroll) {
        doScroll = false;
        top += $container.height();
        console.log("scroll event fired");
        $container.animate({scrollTop: top}, '700', 'swing', function() { 
            doScroll = true;
        });
    } 
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.child {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="child red">Child 1</div>
  <div class="child blue">Child 2</div>
  <div class="child red">Child 3</div>
  <div class="child blue">Child 4</div>
  <div class="child red">Child 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like the scrolling event gets called one more time after the animation completes. If you add a timeout `setTimeout(function() { doScroll = true }, 100);` then it "works". It still only scrolls down and to be honest, there has to be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there are three issues in your code, which creates the confusion:

1. The `scroll` event [cannot be cancelled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll).
2. `$.animate` the `scrollTop` will trigger a `scroll` event right after the complete function has run.
3. All animations will be queued an executed, not matter what value `doScroll` has.

The biggest problem here is the additional `scroll` event triggered by the animation. To overcome this, you have to carefully manage the event handling, e.g. by skipping over the event triggered by the animation.

For an example, [see the working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dx2r2k9y/1/), which also clears the animation queue after each run.

Comment: Works fine in Chome and FF but IE11 is having some problems - sometimes it works, somtimes one or two panels are being skipped. I assume this relates to whether the cursor is on the scrollable div or not - but I'm not sure yet.

Comment: The fiddle is working fine for me in IE11. Can you provide an other example?

Comment: I assume this had something to do with my Logitech mouse / Setpoint software, probably sending too many / delayed scroll events.

Comment: I forked your fiddle and cleaned it up.  It now scrolls both directions and its a little simpler. https://jsfiddle.net/dx2r2k9y/1/

Comment: Thanks @Wil, I updated the answer with your version of the fiddle!

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would use location hashes `#`.

If you place anchors within your divs which contain `href="#child1"` for example then you would be able to scroll to them with javascript by doing `location.hash="#child1"`.

For animated scrolling to location hashes, check out [this script](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/)

Comment: The demo you linked to does not show how to handle scroll events, only click.

Comment: also, how would I know at what # I am and to what anchor I should scroll next?